# algorithm that checks if a tree is full and complete

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree

I am trying to write a method that will return true if a binary tree is full and complete (each node has 2 childern or none and all the leaves of the tree are at the same depth).

my idea is to use recursion. I will check for any node if it's left son has number of childern that euqals to it's right son's number of childern. If so - I will return true, otherwise false;

The algorithem will look like this:

```
public class Utils {


public boolean isFullCompleteTree(Tree<Integer> t) {
        TreeInfo rootInfo = isFullCompleteTree(t.getRoot());
        return rootInfo.valid;
    }

    public TreeInfo isFullCompleteTree(Node<Integer> node) {
        boolean valid = true;

        if (node == null) {
            return new TreeInfo(true, 0);
        }

        TreeInfo rightInfo = isFullCompleteTree(node.goRight());
        TreeInfo leftInfo = isFullCompleteTree(node.goLeft());

        if ((!rightInfo.valid) || (!leftInfo.valid)) {
            valid = false;
        }
        if (rightInfo.numChildern != leftInfo.numChildern) {
            valid = false;
        }
        return new TreeInfo(valid, rightInfo.numChildern + leftInfo.numChildern
                + 1);
    }
}

class TreeInfo {
    public boolean valid;
    public int numChildern;

    public TreeInfo(boolean valid, int numChildern) {
        this.valid = valid;
        this.numChildern = numChildern;
    }
}
```

I didn't put the tree implementation but it is pretty straightforward.

The idea of the algorithem is to check if in every node the number of right son's childern is equals to the left son's childern. if a tree is not full and complete - then in some node this rule will not apply.

Do you think that my alogrithem is corret or am I missing something?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This can be done in a much more simple manner; but I believe this should go on code reviews rather than here

Comment: I am not asking about the code as I am asking about the correctnes of the algorithem. and simple how? in terms of complexity? I think that it is pretty good o(n) - as n is number of nodes.

Comment: You should better post your algorithm's pseudocode. IMHO it's much more clear to read.

Comment: If the code _works as intended_ and you are seeking improvements, you can post at the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site, and delete it from Stack Overflow. If you do that it would be a good idea to include your tree implementation as well.

Comment: algorithm's pseudocode: return true if for each node - the number of right childern is equals to the number of left childern. false otherwise.

Comment: I don't know if the code is working. I did not check it. I am asking about the idea not the code.

Comment: @user1007665 The best course of action for validating your implementation would be to write unit tests (look into [JUnit](http://junit.org/)) which check your code's output given a variety of inputs. Usually, if you can write and run the tests, you'll be able to figure out whether or not your algorithm is correct.

Comment: what about special cases.. How do I know if I covered everything? JUint is not some magic trick that validate stuff, it just a techincal tool, I am hoping that someone can valid or disproof my pesudo code (not the code itself)

Comment: Why do you want to do both checks at once? Define two methods that each do one check, and then combine them...

Comment: what do you mean *both* checks? I am counting for each node how many children it has, and compare it with his "brother". I can do the counting and comparing seprated but then I will need to save for each node the number of children it has, and also go over the tree twice.

Comment: @user1007665: here you create new objects every time. Encoding them in a simple `int` (for instance use a negative number for `false`), would already help since creating an object is an expensive operation as well (actually in many cases not even constant time)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking for a more mathematical proof of your algorithm. Your algorithm is correct. The proof can be done simply using deduction.

**`Lemma 1:`** If a full and complete binary tree has a number of nodes equals to `N`, then it's leaves has a depth of `log2(N+1)`

This lemma itself can be proved by deduction:

For `N = 1` it's correct.

For `N > 1`, its left and right sub-trees each has `(N-1)/2` nodes, and both have their leaves of `depth = log2((N-1)/2+1)`, so now the depth will be `log2((N-1)/2+1) + 1 = log2(((N-1)/2+1) * 2) = log2(N-1 + 2) = log2(N+1)`

By your definition, "full and complete" means "each node has 2 children or none and all the leaves of the tree are at the same depth"

So if both subtrees are "full and complete", and they have the same number of nodes (say it's `M`), then by **`Lemma 1`**, all leaves in both subtrees will have the same `depth = log2(M+1)`, and their depth in the original tree will all be `log2(M+1) + 1`.

And also the root has 2 children, plus both subtrees are "full and complete" means all notes have 2 children or none. Then by definition the original tree is also "full and complete".

And again, as fge@ mentioned, this can be implemented in a much simpler way. Like just checking if the max depth == log2(N-1)